# Get top 25% data Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Column1       Column2
a             0.34
b             0.25
c             0.75
d             1.5
e             0.31
f             2.45
g             7.89
```

How to calculate the top 25% of data with highest value in Column2.
For example, with 7 rows, top 25% would be 1.75 ~ 2

Output:

```
Column1         Column2
g               7.89
f               2.45
```

Comment: Top 25% needs more clarity in this case, do you want to 25% highest values by count, or by the value (eg range) of your values? The best way to clarify this is to add expected output

Comment: To clarify, it's 25% highest values, and not count. Thanks @Erfan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do `qcut`

```
df[pd.qcut(df.Column2,q=4,labels=[1,2,3,4])==4]
  Column1  Column2
5       f     2.45
6       g     7.89
```

---

```
pd.qcut(df.Column2,q=4)
0     (0.325, 0.75]
1    (0.249, 0.325]
2     (0.325, 0.75]
3     (0.75, 1.975]
4    (0.249, 0.325]
5     (1.975, 7.89]
6     (1.975, 7.89]
Name: Column2, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(0.249, 0.325] < (0.325, 0.75] < (0.75, 1.975] < (1.975, 7.89]]
```

Answer (score 3):

As you clarified in the comments (*"25% highest values"*), this is basically values higher than the `75th quantile`. So we can use [`Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
q75 = df['Column2'].quantile(q=0.75)
df[df['Column2'].ge(q75)]
```

Or shorter with `DataFrame.query`:

```
df.query('Column2 >= Column2.quantile(q=0.75)')
```

```
  Column1  Column2
5       f     2.45
6       g     7.89
```

Comment: OP's calculation does not suggest that though. OP calculates 25% as `7*.25`

Comment: He just clarified it's the opposite of what you're saying

Comment: Ahh, I see. I will delete my answer in that case :)